# What's the proper way to map over a single column in a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Usually I do something like

```scala
val fun = udf { x => ... }
df.withColumn("new", fun(df.col("old"))).drop("old").withColumnRename("new", "old")
```

is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do the following :

```
val df : DataFrame = ???
val fun = udf { x => ... }
df.withColumn("old", fun(df.col("old")))
```

But you'll loose the information from the old column, so be careful on not loosing valuable date.

**PS:** Of course, a column is accessible in different ways in Spark. So I let you decide on which to use.